# Populate a div with online users in CodeIgniter using Ajax call (updated every 10 sec)

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I need to populate a div with records from my database,every 10 seconds, using Ajax calls. I know I must create a JSON object first, and then pass it to the Ajax function. That's what I tried.
**//Updated source**
The code is below:

**Controller**

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class HomePage extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
       $this->load->model('home_page_model');
       $data['query'] = json_encode($this->home_page_model->onlineUsers());
       $this->load->view('homepage', $data);
    }
    public function AjaxUsers()
    {
//When I placed here the following, got an errow about query variable not defined
//the problem is the $data variable which when not loaded with the view
//throws en error. I don't know what to do further...
//$this->load->model('home_page_model');
//$data['query'] = json_encode($this->home_page_model->onlineUsers());

    }
}
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php

    class home_page_model extends CI_Model {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function onlineUsers() {
            $this -> db -> select('user_name,status,thumb') -> from('users') -> where('status', 'Online');
            $query = $this -> db -> get();
            if ($query -> num_rows > 0) {
                return $query -> result();

            } else {
                'There are no results';
            }   
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**And finally my View**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/csustyles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function()
{
$('.user-records').load('<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/HomePage/');
}, 1000);
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>

<div id="body">
<div class="user-records"></div>
</div>
    <p class="footer">
    Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see ajax calls, nor json outputs though. What did you try on that part?

Comment: But there is no controller method for the ajax call itself? You need to have the homepage/index call as one controller method and another for the ajax call. Also you cant run the php code in the view more than once, so you will need to have the jquery do the updates

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an AJAX controller that will actually output the needed data.
Let's call it `ajax_controller` (though it can also be a method in your existing controller, like `homepage->online_users_ajax`, it doesn't *have* to be a separate controller).

Then, you need to call your new controller every 10 seconds using Javascript (jQuery). Here's an example of jQuery code without the timer:

```
$('.online-users').load('<?php echo base_url('ajax_controller'); ?>');
```

So, the point is that `ajax_controller` is rendering the content and jQuery populates your existing div with the rendered data.

Comment: i managed somehow to make a progress, but as i see the .load jquery function it actually 'reloads' the div causing it to overlap it self!!! :)).Its not a clear 100% ajax call so im guessing this is why.I will update the source code for you guys to give me some ideas

Comment: You only need to call your ajax method with the `.load` function, not the `index` method. Like this: `$('.user-records').load('<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/homePage/ajaxUsers');`
Also, read [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class_and_method_naming).

Comment: Also, no need to delete what you originally had in the `.user-records` div as that data is loaded the first time and will be replaced on each ajax call. Make sure the ajax page URL outputs the data in the format you need - you can check that by visiting the URL in your browser (`/index.php/homePage/ajaxUsers`).

Answer (score 1):

Your only interested in the data to fill a div, so an ajax controller with no view output is ideal, unless you didn't want to parse the json object in javascript via some sort of template library :?

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajax_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function online_users(){

        //load the model
        //
        $this->load->model('UserModel');

        //grab the data
        $data = &$this->UserModel->usersOnline();

        if(!$data)//expecting array/object or boolean
        {
            echo json_encode(array(
               'error'   =>  1 
            ));
        }

        //send to the browser
        $this->output
             ->set_content_type('application/json')
             ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                 'error' =>  0,
                 'data' =>  $data
             )));
    }

}
```

-

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserModel extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * usersOnline
     * 
     * @return mixed (boolean or array/object)
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function usersOnline(){

        try
        {

           $data = $this->db
                 ->select('user_name, status, thumb')
                 ->from('users')
                 ->where('status', 'online')
                 ->get();

           if( !$data OR !$data->num_rows > 0)
               throw new Exception('No data found from last request__ ' . __CLASS__ . __METHOD__);

        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            log_message('error', $e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        //we must have data?
        return $data;
    }
}
```

-

```
$route['users-online'] = 'ajax_controller/online_users';
```

-

```
<!-- Add this to head section -->
        <script>
            //Assign base_url as a global variable
            var BASEURL = "<?= base_url() ?>";
        </script>
```

-

```
<div id="usersOnline"></div>


        <script>
            (function($){

                var ajaxRequests = {

                    init : function(){
                        if(document.getElementById('usersOnline'))
                        {
                            this.onlineUsers;
                        }
                    },
                    onlineUsers : function(){

                        var scope = $("#usersOnline");

                        //ajax setup
                        var doAjax = function(div){
                            $.ajax({
                               url : BASEURL + "users-online",
                               type: 'GET',
                               context : div,
                               beforeSend : function(){
                                   $(this).html("<span class='loading-icon'>&nbsp;</span>");
                               },
                               success : function(callback){
                                   if(callback.error == 1)
                                   {
                                       return;
                                   }

                                   //$(this) == context => #usersOnline
                                   //
                                   //obviously the json object needs to be parsed first!!!!!!!
                                   //
                                   $(this).html(callback.data);

                               }
                            });
                        }

                        //run and run
                        window.setInterval(function(){
                            doAjax(scope);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }

                //ready?
                $(function(){
                   ajaxRequests.init(); 
                });

            })(jQuery);
        </script>
```